# open textbox when button clicked with ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I want to open text box when button is clicked with ajax.
here is my html code
[image]
here in my ajax code

[image]
here is my php code
'

I'm new about Ajax and PHP.Actually I do not know how can I  build `gelirturugetir.php`

Comment: use jquery show and hide to show the textbox on button click.

Comment: Please remove the images and post the code directly in the body of your post.

Comment: @user3040610 ı searched about that I can use.I will try.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tur').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "gelirturugetir.php",
            method: POST, //because your php awaiting POST
            data: 'key=val',
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function( xhr ) {
               //do some staff before request start
               $("#my-textbox-id").show(); //show textbox
            }
        }).done(function (json) {
            //do some staff after request complete
            console.log(json);
            $("#my-textbox-id").hide(); //hide textbox
        });
    })
})
```

Because your ajax request is require JSON data type as answer, add appropriate  header on server side:

```
  ...
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($Verilter);
?>
```